# Idiom to describe a poorly executed task

Tags: idioms, idiom-request, idioms-in-context

Are there any idioms to describe a situation where the task given was very poorly executed, nothing can be done to re-do the task, and the task ends up a failure.

Comment: There is a [**lost cause**](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/lost+cause) but it says nothing about how *well* it is done. It might be very well done, but fails for reasons outside of itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also came across ***fiasco, complete/total disaster***, and in a less formal scenario ***washout, bust or flop***.

Answer (score 1):

One idiom that could describe this situation is “An epic fail”.